# Xcode fails to build new projects (12.4) - Could not build Objective-C module 'SwiftUI'

Tags: swift, xcode

As soon as I create an Xcode project I can't build and have a bunch of errors (Xcode version 12.4)

```
Could not build Objective-C module 'SwiftUI'
```

[image]

Comment: what your minimum ios version for the project? did you try to close and reopen xcode?

Comment: @aiwiguna my iOS deployment target is set to 14.4 and I did close and reopen Xcode, tried restarting my laptop but still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! MY Xcode was using the wrong toolchain version even tho I tried to uninstall Xcode and reinstall it.

Make sure you have selected the correct version, in my case since I was running Xcode 12.4, I had to use version 12.4 for toolchains. It's weird that Xcode did not manually change it since I updated.

To updated version:

> Xcode > Preferences > Components > Toolchains > and then select your
> version